# Installing silverstripe 2.4.10 on Postgres constantly fails on db connection

Tags: php, postgresql, installation, redhat, silverstripe

I am trying to install Silverstripe 2.4.10 on Red Hat with Postgres.

So I downloaded v2.4.10, I added a new vHost to my httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
ServerName silverstripe.localhost 
ServerAlias silverstripe.localhost 
ServerAdmin root@silverstripe.localhost 
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/SilverStripe-cms-v2.4.10 
ErrorLog /var/www/html/silverstripe/silverstripe.com-error_log 
CustomLog /var/www/html/silverstripe/silverstripe.com-access_log common 
<Directory "/var/www/html/silverstripe/SilverStripe-cms-v2.4.10"> 
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
AllowOverride All 
Order allow,deny 
Allow from all 
</Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

I downloaded the postgres package and unpacked it into /var/www/html/silverstripe/SilverStripe-cms-v2.4.10.

I navigate to the SilverStripe's sub domain URL: 
http://silverstripe.localhost/

It will take me to install.php, I add my Postgres database credentials but Silverstripe constantly tells me it can't connect to the database.

I verified my db credentials by creating a small PHP script:

```
<?php 
$db = pg_connect("host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=SS_mysite user=silverstripe password="); 
$result = pg_query($db, "SELECT * FROM test_table_pgtest");

while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) { 
echo "Id: $row[0] Name: $row[1]"; 
echo "<br />\n"; 
} 
?>
```

The script executes fine, but silverstripe does not accept the same DB credentials. 
Error is: I couldn't find a database server on '127.0.0.1:5432': PostgreSQL requires a valid username and password to determine if the server exists.

That is really annoying.

The Postgres module gives instructions to run: 
dev/build

Unfortunately also this just results in a 404 error. http://silverstripe.localhost/dev/build simply returns a 404 error. 
What else can I do or check to improve on that?

Of course the database does exist and the user does work (see my test script that runs quite well).

Also this dev/build thing does not work at all, it is kind of not clear from the documentation if this is intend to work *before* you run the installer at all. 
Cause if so ... its kind of strange that the Postgres module tells users to run that script upfront installation.

Comment: Have you tried to use 'localhost' instead of '127.0.0.1' ?
You can also bypass the installer and initialize you db connection using an _ss_environment.php file in your webroot, and define the following:
define('SS_PGSQL_DATABASE_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('SS_PGSQL_DATABASE_USERNAME', 'postgres');
define('SS_PGSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD', 'postgres');

Where you replace 'postgres' with your username and password

Comment: You might also want to try using a postgres user with a password. Looking at the code of the module, a passwordless connection would generate the following : pg_connect("host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=SS_mysite user=silverstripe");, so no "password=", which can be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following configuration in mysite/_config.php should work (this bypasses the procedure followed in the installer), and assumes postgresql constants SS_PGSQL_DATABASE_SERVER, SS_PGSQL_DATABASE_USERNAME,and SS_PGSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD have been defined in _ss_environment.php:

```
global $database;
$database = 'SS_mysite';
require_once('conf/ConfigureFromEnv.php');
global $databaseConfig;
$databaseConfig['type'] = 'PostgreSQLDatabase';
$databaseConfig['server'] = SS_PGSQL_DATABASE_SERVER;
$databaseConfig['username'] = SS_PGSQL_DATABASE_USERNAME;
$databaseConfig['password'] = SS_PGSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD;
```

Comment: there where two additional changes in the SilverStripe API that I did not know: They changed the server config "port" to be no more required to be part of the host condition, so my config was in that sense wrong that I wrote define('SS_DATABASE_SERVER', '127.0.0.1:5432'); instead of define('SS_DATABASE_SERVER', '127.0.0.1');. But with your comments I was able to resolve that.